# jQuery .submit() not working after ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to call jQuery.submit() function after ajax response. Where ajax response contains a form. But it couldn't call jQuery.submit() function when i submit the form without refresh.

I prepend the form with the existing code after successfull ajax response

```
success: function(data) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".name_wrapper").prepend('<form class="replyName"><textarea name="name"   placeholder="Write your name"></textarea><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Reply your name</button></form>');
},
error: function(data) {}
```

So after adding the form to the existing code. When i tried to submit the form it's got refresh instead of calling the function. How to make jQuery.submit() workable from ajax response?

```
 $(".replyName").submit(function(event) {
     alert(event.currentTarget[0].value);
 });
```

Comment: Add the `submit` event in the success function of your ajax call.

Comment: the function could be calling from immediately ajax response form or the form which are already exist in that page.

Comment: You need to bind it again, see awnser. It didn't exist at the moment you binded the `.submit` event

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `submit` event after you `prepend` the form. Because `event`'s are only binded to the elements after the `DOM` is loaded.

And because the `prepend` the form dynamically, `jQuery` doesn't know which element it has to submit, because it didn't exist at the time it *binded* the event.

```
success: function(data) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".name_wrapper").prepend('<form class="replyName"><textarea name="name"   placeholder="Write your name"></textarea><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Reply your name</button></form>');

        $( ".replyName").submit(function( event ) {
            alert(event.currentTarget[0].value);

            event.preventDefault();
        });
},
error: function(data) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is not created in the document, you cant listen to submit event, unless you put the event listener after you prepend form into the dom

```
success: function(data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".name_wrapper").prepend('<form class="replyName"><textarea name="name"   placeholder="Write your name"></textarea><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Reply your name</button></form>');
    $(".replyName").submit(function(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget[0].value);
});

},
error: function(data) {}
```

You can also handle the event from body dom

```
$('body').on('submit', '.replyName', function(e){
  // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing you can do:

Either you can rebind the click function like this:

```
success: function(data) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".name_wrapper").prepend('<form class="replyName"><textarea name="name"   placeholder="Write your name"></textarea><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Reply your name</button></form>');
 $('button').bind('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(event.currentTarget[0].value);
});
},
error: function(data) {}
```

or you can try this

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  // code here
});
```